# MySQL - Show All Rows From Multiple Tables Maching Value

Tags: mysql

Sir,
I am connected to my database & I have three tables like,

tbl_borrow:

```
borrow_id  |  member_id  | date_borrow           | due_date
490           15           2015-08-26 18:34:18     01/09/2015
491           15           2015-08-26 18:34:27     30/08/2015
500           20           2015-08-27 19:12:20     01/09/2015
```

tbl_borrowdetails:

```
boook_id  |  borrow_id  | borrow_status           | date_return
34             490         pending                   
1              491         returned                 30/08/2015
```

and, tbl_book:

```
book_id | book_title
34        Boook Name 01
1         Book Name 02
```

Now I Just need a code to return values for a memebr_id from these tables like:

```
book_id | book_title | borrow_status | date_borrow        | due_date|  date_return 
34        Book Name 01   pending      2015-08-26 18:34:18  01/09/2015
1         Book Name 02   returned     2015-08-26 18:34:27  30/08/2015  30/08/2015
```

Now Please help me to make this happen. I am a beginner & very new with this type or situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go back to the books and learn about `JOIN`. SO doesn't write code for you, you have to learn the basics, make an attempt, and then post what yuo tried if you can't get it working.

Comment: If you have already tried something, edit your question with your code & what it returns.

Comment: Sir, I have tried JOIN LEFT but can't make this table looks like. I have found like this :

    book_id | borrow_status | date_borrow | due_date | date_return

Can't get the book_title and my code is just returning only a row! Not all the rows for a member_id.

Comment: Show your code, post what you tried and the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using LEFT OUTER JOINs:-

```
SELECT a.book_id,
        a.book_title,
        b.borrow_status,
        c.date_borrow,
        c.date_due,
        b.date_return
FROM tbl_book a
LEFT OUER JOIN tbl_borrowdetails b
ON a.book_id = b.boook_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_borrow c
ON b.borrow_id = c.borrow_id
```

But it seems rather strange that your tables seem to have borrow details above the basic borrow.

Comment: Thanks Sir,
I have tried your code and when,

echo $row['borrow_status']; I found Undefined variable warning.

Last time I have tried that,

$sql = "SELECT * FROM borrowdetails WHERE borrow_id = $borrow_id ";
    echo $row['borrow_status'];

Its returning undefined variable warning.

Comment: There was a typo on borrow status (now fixed). But I would expect that to give an error rather than returning nothing. Instead of using echo try print_r($row);

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_borrow t1
JOIN tbl_borrowdetails t2 ON t1.borrow_id=t2.borrow_id
JOIN tbl_book t3 ON t2.boook_id=t3.book_id;
```